# Library search giving javascript error in IE8

Tags: sharepoint-server, ie8

Searching in a document library search box gives the following error in IE8. Sometimes the search works and sometimes it does not. It starts out ok, but after 2 or 3 searches the error appears. The error messages are different which I am pasting below.

The search seems to working fine with IE10, Chrome 39 and Firefox 33.

Is this a known issue with IE8 since I checked that IE8 is supported by SP 2013.

**Error Message 1**

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; openframe/30.0.0.6.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; MS-RTC LM 8)
>   Timestamp: Tue, 2 Dec 2014 18:35:26 UTC
>
> Message: Syntax error
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 30151
>   Code: 0
>   URI: xyz.com/_layouts/15/inplview.js?rev=JuQvHna5pA8GjBqyCrETww%3D%3D

**Error Message 2**

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; openframe/30.0.0.6.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; MS-RTC LM 8)
>   Timestamp: Tue, 2 Dec 2014 18:45:58 UTC
>
> Message: Syntax error
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 30151
>   Code: 0
>   URI: xyz.com/_layouts/15/inplview.js?rev=JuQvHna5pA8GjBqyCrETww%3D%3D
>
> Message: Syntax error
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 30151
>   Code: 0
>   URI: xyz.com/_layouts/15/inplview.js?rev=JuQvHna5pA8GjBqyCrETww%3D%3D
>
> Message: Syntax error
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 30151
>   Code: 0
>   URI: xyz.com/_layouts/15/inplview.js?rev=JuQvHna5pA8GjBqyCrETww%3D%3D
>
> Message: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 155185
>   Code: 0
>   URI: xyz.com/_layouts/15/core.js?rev=uA2xjCXmuYM5ARP8g3eTSA%3D%3D
>
> Message: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 155185
>   Code: 0
>   URI: xyz.com/_layouts/15/core.js?rev=uA2xjCXmuYM5ARP8g3eTSA%3D%3D
>
> Message: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 155185
>   Code: 0

```
 URI: https:/xyz.com/_layouts/15/core.js?rev=uA2xjCXmuYM5ARP8g3eTSA%3D%3D
```

> Message: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 155185
>   Code: 0

```
URI: xyz.com/_layouts/15/core.js?rev=uA2xjCXmuYM5ARP8g3eTSA%3D%3D
```